# Is it <centre> or <center>?

Tags: html, center

Is the tag used for centering elements called `<center>` or `<centre>`?

I know the `<centre>` or `<center>` tag is not used anymore, but which one is the correct one?

I am confused. Visual studio code says that `<center>` is wrong, but only `<centre>` works with Microsoft Edge.

Edit: Microsoft Edge now works with `<center>`. It was `<centre>` that didn't work with Microsoft Edge

So which one is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) but this tag has been deprecated in favor of CSS property [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)

> Visual studio code says that  is wrong

It doesn't say is wrong, but deprecated/obsolete

> Edit: Microsoft Edge now works with `<center>`. It was `<centre>` that didn't work with Microsoft edge

In HTML5 you can create custom tags (therego `centre` works in all modern browsers), but in older browsers you have to set them as `display:block` otherwise it won't work.

Best example I can remember is the [reset.css](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) from Eric Meyers

> ```
> /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
> article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
> footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
>   display: block;
> }
> ```

Comment: Then why the visual studio code says center is wrong, and why only centre works with edge?

Comment: @ppwater I've updated the answer take a look

Comment: @ppwater I've updated the answer again to mee the edited question

Comment: yeah, well. though, nice answer with nice explanation. thanks